# Как перекрасить предыдущий и следующий блок за текущим?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть блоки, в которых только соседи(предыдущий и последующий) блока с классом `.active` должны быть окрашены в красный цвет (не касается блоков с `active`!), а все остальные в зеленый; при этом количество всех блоков может быть больше, в том числе и активных, но последние всегда идут вместе друг за дружкой и не всегда по центру. Как это можно сделать? [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/dmv179cn/) Условия: `html` трогать нельзя. В идеале хотелось бы обойтись без скриптов, но, если без них никак, то хотелось бы узнать и такой вариант

```css
.owl-item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.owl-item.active + .owl-item {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item">first</div>
<div class="owl-item active">second</div>
<div class="owl-item active">third</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
```

Comment: а если два блока `.active`, то какие надо окрашивать?

Comment: какой ожидаемый результат для приведенного примера? Вообще стоит добавить больше примеров разметки и ожидаемых результатов, сейчас непонятно, как именно все должно выглядеть в итоге

Comment: @lexxl внешние к ним ближайшие соседи, сами блоки `active` не трогать

Comment: @Grundy в ответе ниже приведен искомый результат, но только со скриптом. если есть хитрый способ на `css`, то будет круто!

Comment: @Вася, в ответе ниже разметка отличается от приведенной в вопросе

Comment: @Grundy кстати да, в моем варианте такой метод не прокатывает..

Comment: он должен был закрасить 2 зеленых блока по центру и красные оставить по бокам https://jsfiddle.net/dmv179cn/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чистым CSS этого не сделать. С помощью jQuery элементарно

```js
$('.active').prev(':not(.active)').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.active').next(':not(.active)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

```css
.owl-item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item">first</div>
<div class="owl-item active">second</div>
<div class="owl-item active">third</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
```

Comment: а вы ведь смухлявали и упростили пример, для моего варианта такой способ не прокатывает..
https://jsfiddle.net/dmv179cn/1/

Comment: Сделано точно по постановке задачи: `соседи(предыдущий и последующий) блока с классом .active должны быть окрашены в красный цвет, а все остальные в зеленый`. У вас два элемента с классом active, их соседи окрашены в красный. Или вам надо чтобы это не распространялось на сами элементы с классом active?

Comment: да, именно, чтобы не распространялось, иначе получается все блоки окрашиваются в 1 цвет. дополню этом момент в описании

Comment: Элементарно. Исправил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Без скриптов это сделать нельзя, так как в CSS отсутствует селектор, определяющий предыдущий элемент. Поэтому этот случай нужно обработать скриптом, например так:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.active'), function(active) {
  var prev = active.previousElementSibling;
  if (prev && !prev.classList.contains('active')) {
    prev.classList.add('prev');
  }
});
```

```css
.owl-item {
  background-color: green;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.owl-item.active + .owl-item:not(.active),
.prev {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="owl-item">first</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item">first</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item">first</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
<div class="owl-item active">active</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
<div class="owl-item">fourth</div>
```